# Narrowing conversion with template parameter (MSVC14)

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, narrowing

Upon upgrading to MSVC 2015 (from MSVC 2013), I started getting warnings for the following code:

```
template< unsigned int i0, unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2, unsigned int i3 >
static __m128 Constant( )
{
    static __m128i v = {
        ((i0&0x000000FF) >> 0 ), ((i0&0x0000FF00) >> 8), ((i0&0x00FF0000) >> 16), ((i0&0xFF000000) >> 24), 
        ((i1&0x000000FF) >> 0 ), ((i1&0x0000FF00) >> 8), ((i1&0x00FF0000) >> 16), ((i1&0xFF000000) >> 24), 
        ((i2&0x000000FF) >> 0 ), ((i2&0x0000FF00) >> 8), ((i2&0x00FF0000) >> 16), ((i2&0xFF000000) >> 24), 
        ((i3&0x000000FF) >> 0 ), ((i3&0x0000FF00) >> 8), ((i3&0x00FF0000) >> 16), ((i3&0xFF000000) >> 24) };
    return *(__m128*)&v;
}
```

Produces the following (with `Constant<0x7FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF>()`):

```
note: see reference to function template instantiation '__m128 Constant<2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647>(void)' being compiled
warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'char' requires a narrowing conversion
```

The `__m128i` union is defined inside `emmintrin.h`, as a union of arrays with several different types, which represent an MMX register. To list initialize the structure, you must use the first type declared in the union, in this case, `__int8`. According to MSVC 2013 documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx), `__int8` maps to `char`, I would assume the same for MSVC 2015. So, it seems like the warning is valid, because even though the template parameters are non-types, not all of the fields would fit into `char` type after conversion.

My question is why does MSVC 2013 not give a warning for this (as it seems like a core c++11 issue)? Also, is there a 'nice' way to resolve the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out the shift-mask-cast:

```
template<unsigned n, unsigned value>
/*constexpr*/ int8_t get_byte() {
  return static_cast<int8_t>(0xFF & (value >> (n*8)));
}
```

Then use it:

```
template<unsigned i0, unsigned i1, unsigned i2, unsigned i3>
static __m128 Constant( )
{
  static __m128i v = {
    get_byte<0,i0>(), get_byte<1,i0>(), get_byte<2,i0>(), get_byte<3,i0>(),
    get_byte<0,i1>(), get_byte<1,i1>(), get_byte<2,i1>(), get_byte<3,i1>(),
    get_byte<0,i2>(), get_byte<1,i2>(), get_byte<2,i2>(), get_byte<3,i2>(),
    get_byte<0,i3>(), get_byte<1,i3>(), get_byte<2,i3>(), get_byte<3,i3>(),
  };
  return *(__m128*)&v;
}
```

note that `get_byte` returns a signed 8 bit integer.

Notice how the symmetry of the above is really obvious.

Comment: Okay, thanks - that is a fairly nice enough way to silence the warning. But the answer doesn't explain the difference between the VS versions.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I'm not at all surprised by a failure of VS to match C++11's requirements?  MSVC 2013 is only a quarter-baked implementation of C++11.  MSVC2015 might be half-baked.

Comment: The new warnings are part of the C++11 standard compliance in VS 2015 for initializer lists. They are required by the standard in those cases. And at this point, C++11 support in MSVC2015's latest CTP is "mostly baked". See [this table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx) for a list of features by VS version.

Comment: Note that C4838 is new for VS 2015 which is why it doesn't come up in VS 2013.

Comment: @chuck that chart claims 2013 had compliant future -- not true.  Fixed in 2015?  Also, lack of "expression" SFINAE *still* in a 2015 "alpha, may not be out in 2017" is not encouraging (and crippling for some uses).  What support there is in 2013 runs into internal compiler errors (once, I think, from `using` instead of `typedef` and `typename blah<>::type`).  Finally, support in such an alpha is not support.  It is an experimental variant of an unreleased product!

Comment: If you have run into issues especially ICE, be sure to [file bugs on VS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)

Answer (score 0):

@Chuck Walbourn - "Note that C4838 is new for VS 2015 which is why it doesn't come up in VS 2013."